# Prove that order of the subgroup divides the order of its normalizer

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand a very long proof but don’t understand how the order of the subgroup divides the order of its normalizer.

I can show that normalizer divides the order of the group but not that.

I know about orbits and stabilizers and think it has something to do with them. Please help.

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $N_G(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$, then $H \leq N_G(H)$ (i.e. $H$ normalizes itself, because conjugating an element of $H$ by an element of $h$ can't take you out of $H$). As $N_G(H)$ is also a subgroup, Lagrange's theorem applies.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem asserts that the order  of *any* subgroup divides the order of the group, and a subgroup is also a subgroup of its normaliser.

Comment: Do you know that whenever $H$ is a subgroup of $N$, that $|H|$ divides $|N|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over thinking it!

Order of the subgroup divides the order of the group by Lagrange’s theorem.

It is clear that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N$. Because it is contained in $N$, contains the identity and is closed in $N$.